# How can I stay on 4.8 kernels, or anyway not upgrade to 4.10 kernels?

Tags: apt, package-management

[There is a serious bug with the intel GPU drivers shipping with Zesty that causes random soft locks and data loss multiple times per day due to double frees.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1677673) Intel fixed the issue on their end in February as part of a 25-commit patch series and there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to cherry-pick the fix onto the kernel tip. I'd still have the problem even if I compiled my own kernel from ltorvalds' HEAD.

However, yakkety's 4.8.x Ubuntu kernels work perfectly, and as long as yakkety is supported, I can keep getting kernel updates if only I:

1. add the yakkety sources to my computer (done)
2. downgrade linux-generic, linux-image-generic, linux-tools-generic and linux-headers-generic to the latest available 4.8 version (done)
3. prevent any newer kernel from being installed (???)

I've attempted to achieve (3) by <kbd>F</kbd>orbidding version packages in Aptitude, but apparently you can only forbid a single version of a package.

I can also put the package on <kbd>h</kbd>old, but then I will probably miss out on security upgrades from `unattended-upgrades`.

Finally I can do this manually, which adds a bit of toil in telling aptitude that no, I really do want to downgrade everything and remove the new things and only keep the old things.

How can I achieve this?

```
$ apt policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 4.8.0.51.63
  Candidate: 4.10.0.20.22
  Version table:
     4.10.0.20.22 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.10.0.19.21 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.8.0.51.63 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.0.49.61 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.0.22.31 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
     4.4.0.77.83 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.4.0.75.81 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Yeah, surprise surprise it appears that only aptitude cares about its own version F'orbids.

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt policy linux-generic`?

Comment: I installed Wily on this laptop, and the Intel GPU drivers caused softlocks. Then I upgraded to Xenial, and the display port monitor kept flickering. Yakkety was perfect, but now Zesty has more kernel panics caused by Intel's GPU drivers. I don't want to assign blame, but this is quite disappointing. :(

Comment: @badp Hardware headaches aren't a 'new' thing.  To answer your question without posting an answer, though, you'd have to run a 'custom' Zesty installation with the 4.8 kernel you see there pinned, and the linux-generic software pinned to the specificed version (same for other dependencies and reverse-dependencies).  However, you will not get patches or security updates from the repositories or the security team at that point, which can be... problematic... if there's a major security hole that gets patched.  (Rolling a custom kernel from the default tends to do this though)

Comment: We can make it to use yakkety for update.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm just pointing out that virtually all of my headaches have, well, a common source.  I've already been running a yakkety kernel and a zesty userland with no obvious issues for about a month now.

Comment: @badp Have you tried pinning the kernel to yakkety?

Comment: @badp I know, i just had a headache from people complaining about hardware recently; the core issue remains the same - pin the kernel version, sacrifice updates and patches.

Comment: @Ravexina that'd be lovely. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove unnecessary lines from your `sources.list`; Only keep `yakkety` and your own version's lines.

Add this line:

```
APT::Default-Release "zesty";
```

to : `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Create a file:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/kernel
```

Add these lines into it:

```
Package: linux-generic
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-generic
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: linux-image-generic
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-image-generic
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: linux-headers-generic
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-headers-generic
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: linux-tools-common
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-tools-common
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: linux-tools-generic
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-tools-generic
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 900
```

You are running `zesty` right? if not change `zesty` with your Ubuntu code name.

Before doing anything check that you don't get a massive update using:

```
apt update
apt list -u
```

---

[Further reading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

Comment: I think he'll only need the 900 pin - default pin priority is 500, anything higher is not gonna be looked at.  he'll need to update this though too for the other dependencies that might depend on linux-generic as well - just saying.

Comment: I can confirm `apt` is satisfied that everything is up to date even without the -10 priority pins.

Comment: I was getting some strange results; So I put them there just in case, @badp thanks for the edit ;)

Comment: ...and even after removing the manual version forbids from aptitude,  aptitude is also satisfied that everything is up to date :)